# Where Clauses not applying - SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this select query:

```
(SELECT TOP (1) TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORID
 FROM TRAINEE 
 INNER JOIN TRASSESSOR ON TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID
 WHERE (TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE = 'E' OR TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE = 'F') AND
       (TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID = TRAINEE.TRAINEEID)
 ORDER BY TRASSESSOR.ENDDATE DESC)
```

The purpose of this is to select the unique `ASESSORID` for the particular `TRAINEEID`

For some reason I'm receiving the same `ASESSORID` for every `TRAINEEID` rather than it filtering to the correct `ASESSORID` based on the joins

Any ideas?

Edit - here is a snippet of the example i'm getting:

```
MISLearnerID    StudentID   MISEmployerID   Courses/Course/MISAssessorID
0295-0003-315032    0295-0003-315032    0295-0003-259362    0295-0001-100053
0295-0003-315032    0295-0003-315032    0295-0003-259362    0295-0001-100053
0624-0001-104878    0624-0001-104878    0295-0003-203134    0295-0001-100053
0624-0001-104878    0624-0001-104878    0295-0003-203134    0295-0001-100053
0624-0001-104878    0624-0001-104878    0295-0003-203134    0295-0001-100053
0624-0001-104878    0624-0001-104878    0295-0003-203134    0295-0001-100053
0295-0003-306792    0295-0003-306792    0295-0003-256903    0295-0001-100053
0295-0003-306792    0295-0003-306792    0295-0003-256903    0295-0004-250714
0295-0003-306792    0295-0003-306792    0295-0003-256903    0295-0001-100053
0295-0003-306792    0295-0003-306792    0295-0003-256903    0295-0001-100053
0295-0003-306792    0295-0003-306792    0295-0003-256903    0295-0001-100053
```

edit 2 - What I am essentially trying to achieve is to select the `ASSESSORID` of `ASSESSORTYPE = 'E' OR 'F'` that is linked to the `TRAINEEID` for each `TRAINEEID` in the query. The query will load hundreds of rows but currently it is not selecting based on `TRAINEEID` but rather looking in the `TRASSESSOR` table and just selecting the first `ASSESSORID` found for each row.

Comment: Why the `TOP 1` clause? That means you'll only get one row...

Comment: There is no such thing as `TOP(1)` in MySQL. Please use the correct tags (or the correct query, if the tags are correct.)

Comment: Good call @axiac, it's still early... MySQL would be `LIMIT 1`

Comment: Hi Sorry - this should just be sql.
`TOP (1)` is used as I am looking only for 1 ID and by using the `ORDER BY` it should return the latest `ASSESSORID` related to the record

Comment: Which DBMS is this targeting? Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, SQLite?

Comment: `just be sql` ... every product is different, you should really tag with a database.  By the way, I can't figure out what the problem is, and not showing us any data increases the likelihood that happening.  Can you show sample data?

Comment: @kchason - sql server - updated tags

Comment: `SELECT TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORID
 FROM TRAINEE 
 INNER JOIN TRASSESSOR ON TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID
 WHERE (TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE = 'E' OR TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE = 'F') ` Does this give the proper result?

Comment: You need to add `TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = @value` to your `WHERE` to get it for a specific user. Here you're just getting it for possibly the same TRAINEE every time.

Comment: The `TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID = TRAINEE.TRAINEEID` condition in the `WHERE` clause is superfluous. It already exists in the `INNER JOIN` clause.

Comment: The `TOP(1)` clause restricts the output to only one row, not to one row for each `TRAINEE` as its seems you want.

Comment: @TZHX - would this look like `WHERE (TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE = 'E' OR TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE = 'F') AND TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = @value`

Comment: @axiac - yes that is the issue i think. would the `@value` resolve this?

Comment: It really depends on what you're actually trying to achieve, and what's arround this subquery. You've not given a concrete example of the problem you're trying to solve, so you can't get a complete solution to it.

Comment: @TZHX posted full script for reference. didn't want to include initially as its quite long

Comment: Take a look at [help/mcve] and focus on the actual problem. A large amount of the query you've posted is totally irrelevant.

Comment: @TZHX - sorry trying to get this as specific as possible. I've added an explanation in the edit removed the full code. As mentioned above, I think the issue is the select is taking place but its not filtering to the `TRAINEEID` but rather selecting the first `ASSESSORID` in the `TRASSESSOR` table

Comment: your joining on TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID and filtering on it. That doesnt makes sense.

Comment: Use a subquery inner join where you select E and F and matches on TRAINEE.TRAINEEID = TRASSESSOR.TRAINEEID then you will get what  you need. INNER JOIN (SELECT top 1 TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORID from TRASSESSOR WHERE TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE in ('E','F') )x on x.TRAINEEID = TRAINEE.TRAINEEID

Comment: @plaidDK - just so I get the correct formatting is this correct `(INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP (1) TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORID FROM TRASSESSOR WHERE TRASSESSOR.ASSESSORTYPE IN ('E','F'))x ON x.TRAINEEID = TRAINEE.TRAINEEID
         ORDER BY TRASSESSOR.ENDDATE DESC)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite difficult to read. You should post examples on how your data looks like and what you expect. From your comments i think you need to do something like this:

**TEST DATA**

Trainee:

[image]

Trassor:

[image]

```
select * from trainee a
inner join (
select trassorid,assesorid from (
select  trassorid,assesorid,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION by trassorid order by assesorid ) as rn from trassor
where assesorid in ('e','f')
)z where rn = 1
) x on x.trassorid = a.traineeid
```

Based on what you say you just need a random assesor if there is several of them. Here i use `ROW_NUMBER` to just select 1 from your trassorID. And then i join this with your traineeids, to match the one random match you need.

**Result**

[image]

And if you need all trassorID matched to your traineeID so you get multiple hits you just remove the `ROW_NUMBER`

```
select * from trainee a
inner join (
select trassorid,assesorid from (
select  trassorid,assesorid from trassor
where assesorid in ('e','f')
)z 
) x on x.trassorid = a.traineeid
```

[image]